# Translating a PowerApp

Tags: powerapps

Is there some simple way to translate an app? In my case, I would like to translate the Leave Request app, given as a template in PowerApps, to Swedish.

The smartest way to make it would be to just to display labels and headers in the new language, without needing to change names of underlying variables. I tried this but it soon became cumbersome, because I had to go into formulas. I can't find a smart way to deal with the Collections! E.g. a name like "Bereavement" (which I want to translate) is also used in formulas.

(That would be no big problem, though, is there only a way to look up every occurence of that name in the app and replace, but I couldn't find a way to do that! And the Leave Request app is quite complex)

Somebody must have done this before, though? Grateful for any guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed now. This was much simpler after learning how the galleries work, and that one can add just another label in the ClearCollect Table script, like "name", where I enter that translated name I want to be displayed. Then it is just to select "name" instead of "type" in the collection data source for the gallery. This way nothing of the original logic is touched. Then it boils down to just some tedious work to translate all the descriptions here and there.
It looked much harder than it was :-)